# Upload Directly to amazon S3 using AJAX returning error: Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files from browser to s3 amazon, I've modified the CORS policy rules to allow the post for the bucket, but I'm getting the error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.</Message>
<ArgumentValue></ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>key</ArgumentName><RequestId>1E0A8DC78C0CEA9A</RequestId><HostId>XN38Qje9hUrGqHNIhtT8CtowX9tXlpyfEoaXb1UNxlsyLOWreh2mKqKVXg1zjLVl</HostId></Error>
```

Here is my request and response, I'm passing key parameter in the right order by still getting this error

[image: http://screencast.com/t/9ZUQO0s9d]

[image: http://screencast.com/t/CL8MKq6l6]

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it, I'm submitting request using FormData

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: here is the code pls check

```
var form_data = new FormData();         
                form_data.append('file',hdlr.file);
                //form_data.append('crop_type',settings.get_cropped_type());
                //form_data.append('attributes',JSON.stringify(file_attr));
                $('input:hidden',$form).each(function(){

                    form_data.append(this.name,this.value);

                });


                //finally post the file through AJAX  
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
                xhr.open("POST", $form[0].action, true);  
                xhr.send(form_data);
```

[image]

Comment: In this screenshot (screencast.com/t/9ZUQO0s9d) the value of the key is myfiles/${filename}. Is this expected?

Comment: amazon s3 post allow myfiles/${filename} for unknown filenames

Comment: Please post your HTML and JS code.

Comment: @RyanWeir thanks, I've posted the code, I'm putting the hidden fields using php as the params are prepared at server

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It kind of looks like your file form field is appearing first in the request.  I can't tell for sure since you have not included the entire request payload in your answer, but it looks like this is appearing just above the "key" field.  AWS ignores all fields in the request after the file field, so all other fields must appear before the file.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html

Comment: Thank you so much. The error was not helpful, but after moving my file field to the end in postman, things started working.

Comment: This suggestion worked perfectly. "file" input has to be the last one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Ray Nicholus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235866/2505542)

It works for me.

```json
{
  "formAttributes": {
    "action": "https://**.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",
    "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data"
  },
  "formInputs": {
    "acl": "public-read",
    "key": "users/2/images/drops-of-water-578897_640.jpg",
    "X-Amz-Credential": "**",
    "X-Amz-Algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
    "X-Amz-Date": "**",
    "Policy": "**",
    "X-Amz-Signature": "**"
  }
}
```

```js
function uploadFile(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  getSignedPost().then(() => {
    const fileEl = document.getElementById('id-file');
    const file = fileEl.files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(uploadCredentials.formInputs).forEach((key) => {
      formData.append(key, uploadCredentials.formInputs[key]);
    });

    // update key to file name
    const key = `users/2/images/${file.name}`;
    formData.set('key', key);
    uploadCredentials.formInputs.key = key;

    // update show data on page
    const el = document.getElementById('id-upload-info');
    el.innerText = JSON.stringify(uploadCredentials, null, 2);

    // IMPORTANCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235866
    // AWS ignores all fields in the request after the file field, so all other fields must appear before the file.
    formData.append('file', file);

    fetch(uploadCredentials.formAttributes.action, {
      method: uploadCredentials.formAttributes.method,
      // headers: {
      //   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      // },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 204) {
          console.log('Successfully uploaded file');
          console.log('-- 204 - no content');

          return `Successfully uploaded file: ${key}`;
        }

        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          return res.text();
        }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message || err);
      });
  });
}
```